# Laravel 5 Has One Relationship with Form Binding

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have spent a pretty good two days on something so simple and small. I have a model called User which has one user note relationship.

On the User model's side I have a belongsTo relationship defined and then the user's model defines a hasOne side of relationship.

The form I am using binds to `$user` model meanwhile the UserNote model has its own table that maps to the user with user_id.

I have been trying to get what is shown below right;

```
{{ Form::textarea($user->notes, null , [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Note Content']) }}
```

Somebody out there to help me figure this out?b All I need is to be able to add a note and if a user has no note yet I should not be getting errors because if I do as shown below I get an error:

```
{{ Form::textarea('UserNote[content]',... }}
```

Your advice would be appreciated.

```
class User{
 ...
 public function note()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(UserNote::class);
  }
}

class UserNote{
 protected $fillable = ['content', 'user_id'];
...
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'user_id');
  }
}
```

Surely the user_id in `$fillable` shouldn't be there in the first place because this only means I can update this table manually whereas I want everything done automatically from controller to form binding.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Update your question with your models please

Comment: @Vuldo I did so Sir thanks in advance.

Comment: @jaysingkar I am no longer getting the error now with the text wrapped in double quotes I do not know why.

Comment: does that your question is resolved ?

Comment: It is not Sir because I need to be able to update the note but because the form in which the textarea is on uses the user model meanwhile the contents of the note are being saved through a different model. i want to be able to prepopulate this text area with the user's note and then be able to save it as an update when user clicks submit button.

Comment: Like when I am trying to get a user with note the returned note is null.  App\User::with('note')->get()

Comment: Show us your controller code that is querying and passing user object to the view.

Comment: which of the two tables contains foreign key ?

Comment: from your code I think it must be in `UserNotes` table. If this is the case just try to swap `belongsTo` with `HasOne`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're doing the relationship wrong.

- User hasOne UserNote
- UserNote belongsTo User

So, you've to swap the relations on those corresponding models.

Secondly, The form's textarea has the parameter list like:

```
public function textarea($name, $value = null, $options = []){}
```

So, the first parameter is obviously the **form_name**. second parameter will be the **value** of the input. You're doing this wrong. 

In your case, that should be ( as I think )

```
{{ Form::textarea('user_note', $user->note , [ 'id' => 'user_note', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Note Content']) }}
```

**Edit**

The property **note** is the method name, you're previously writing like *notes*, the method didn't exist.
**Edit Ends**

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you Sir, @ssl-anik, I will definitely give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: Yes i will deffinately do so.